# Getting InstantiationException in hortonworks stream analytics manager

Tags: streaming, hdf, hortonworks-sam

While trying to run the SAM topology using HDF 3.0.0 sandbox, I am getting the below exception. I have only 2 components in the canvas. 
1) Get input from Kafka Topic
2) Write the contents from the topic to HDFS Sink.

java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.storm.kafka.bolt.selector.DefaultTopicSelector

The engine behind the scene is Storm. While trying to execute the flow, the above mentioned error occurs. I am trying to get more information on the specific error message, but not able to find more help on the internet for Hortonworks Stream Analytics Manager.

Screenshot will make the issue clear. Upon execution of the flow, the exception occurs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors in the streamline.log ? Can you paste the stack trace?

It may be due to some missing classes. You might want to delete and recreate the App and if that doesn't help, raise an issue here - https://github.com/hortonworks/streamline/issues with the relevant information and someone will take a look.